# Facebook FQL Unknown Error when searching for friends links

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm running an FQL Query and I keep this error but can't figure out why because the error message tells me nothing. The query and error are:

```
SELECT backdated_time, can_backdate, caption, created_time, owner, owner_comment, picture, summary, title, url FROM link WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND (strpos(lower(summary),"boston") >=0 OR strpos(lower(owner_comment),"boston") >=0 ) LIMIT 20

Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 1: An unknown error occurred
  thrown in /Facebook/base_facebook.php on line 1254
```

Does anyone have know why this error is coming up? I'm using the Facebook PHP library.

Answer (score 1):

It's choking, the query is too big. Consider using a multi-query, LIMITs of the friends query and some OFFSETs to page through the data.

`fql?q={"friendsquery":"SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0","linkquery": "SELECT backdated_time, can_backdate, caption, created_time, owner, owner_comment, picture, summary, title, url FROM link WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #friendsquery) AND (strpos(lower(summary),'boston') >=0 OR strpos(lower(owner_comment),'boston') >=0 ) LIMIT 20"}`

This current query goes in 80 secs for a friend list of 400.

Here is an example in Python, it's not PHP but the API implementation is the same

```
from facepy import GraphAPI
import time
import urllib
import json

fb_dump = open('dumpfb.txt', 'w')

graph = GraphAPI('MY_ACCESS_TOKEN')

all_posts = []
offset = 0

friendsquery = 'SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 20 OFFSET '+ str(offset)

linksquery = 'SELECT backdated_time, can_backdate, caption, created_time, owner, owner_comment, picture, summary, title, url FROM link WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #friendsquery) AND (strpos(lower(summary),"trinidad") >=0 OR strpos(lower(owner_comment),"trinidad") >=2 ) LIMIT 20'


t0 = time.time()

try:
     my_posts = graph.fql({'friendsquery': friendsquery, 'linksquery': linksquery})
     while my_posts["data"][0]["fql_result_set"]:
         all_posts = all_posts + my_posts["data"]
         offset = offset + 20
   friendsquery = 'SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 20 OFFSET '+ str(offset)
     my_posts = graph.fql({'friendsquery': friendsquery, 'linksquery': linksquery})
     t1 = time.time()
     print t1-t0
     fb_dump.write(json.dumps(all_posts, indent=4))
except GraphAPI.OAuthError, e:
     print e.message
```

Doing a batch query one can get the query down to 25 seconds. Not fast, but an order faster than the previous two queries. I haven't did it in PHP but you should get the gist

That's 20 multi-queries in one batch and one /me/friend call

```
fb_dump = open('lumpfb.txt', 'w')

graph = GraphAPI('MY_ACCESS_TOKEN')


all_posts = []
offset = 0

friendsquery = 'SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 20 OFFSET '

linksquery = 'SELECT backdated_time, can_backdate, caption, created_time, owner, owner_comment, picture, summary, title, url FROM link WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #friendsquery) AND (strpos(lower(summary),\'trinidad\') >=0 OR strpos(lower(owner_comment),\'trinidad\') >=2 ) LIMIT 20'


t0 = time.time()

batch_request = []

try:
     my_friends = graph.get("me?fields=friends")
     counter = len(my_friends["friends"]["data"])
     while counter > 0 :
     friendsquery0 = 'SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 20 OFFSET '+ str(offset)
     the_query = '{"friendsquery":"'+friendsquery0+'","linksquery":"'+linksquery+'"}'
     batch_item = {"method":"GET","relative_url":"fql?q=" + the_query}
     batch_request.append(batch_item)
     offset = offset + 20
     counter = counter - 20
     my_posts = graph.batch(batch_request)
     for post in my_posts:
     all_posts = all_posts + post['data']
     t1 = time.time()
     print t1-t0
except facepy.exceptions.FacepyError, e:
     print e.message
```

Comment: Ok, so you are saying I have to limit the amount of friends that are searched then, because through all off them is too much?

Comment: @DevinDixon You limit **per** query. The next query after this would have the friendsquery as SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 20 **OFFSET 20**

Comment: Ok, I got it.My limit appears to be 50. This answer I want to mark as half correct because while the problem with the unknown error no longer persist, the solution is very inefficient. Unlike Twitter, Facebook's search seems to suck in general.

Comment: @DevinDixon comparing Twitter API and Facebook API is like comparing apples and cows. The query you were attempting is resource intensive, it really is that simple, and I've shown you above how to increase your performance based on documentation from Facebook https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/#multi as well as my own findings from how Facebook themselves execute FQL calls in some of their apps and it seems to be working very well for them